# Constructing a monoidal structure in a closed bicategory

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, higher-category-theory

I wanted to know whether there was a bicategorical version of Eilenberg-Kelly's theorem that allows to reconstruct a monoidal structure on a closed category. Explicitely, if a category $C$ is closed and satisfies that for every objects $a,b \in C$, the functor $[a,[b,-]] : C \rightarrow C$ is representable as an enriched $C$-functor then $C$ is a monoidal category.

Is there a similar result for closed bicategories? Also, which paper(s) give(s) the earliest definition for the notion of a closed bicategory?